# Generate MxN Matrix with MatLab Anonymous Function

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sum, vectorization

Imagine for instance we have the following functions:

```
f = @(n) sin((0:1e-3:1) .* n * pi);
g = @(n, t) cos(n .^ 2 * pi ^2 / 2 .* t);
h = @(n) f(n) * g(n, 0);
```

Now, I would like to be able to enter an array of values for `n` into `h` and return a sum of the results for each value of `n`.

I am trying to be efficient, so I am avoiding the novice for-loop method of just filling out a pre-allocated matrix and summing down the columns. I also tried using `arrayfun` and converting the cell to a matrix then summing that, but it ended up being a slower process than the for-loop.

Does anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are trying to generate? are you saying you want an `M x N` matrix where each element is operated on by that function? Can you give some example data?

Comment: For each value of `n` in the array, `h` will produce a vector of values.  I believe the OP wants to compute the sum of each vector that is produced for each value of `n`.  Also, you don't need to convert the matrix into a `cell`, if the output is a single value (which it is in your case).

Comment: I am trying to generate the result of a Fourier series for the infinite square well problem using my pre-calculated values for the wave numbers. Ideally, I would like a one-liner to generate the sum of h(n) across all n that I specify. This can be done with:


    `F = zeros(1, length(0:1e-3:1));`
    `n = some vector of integers;`
    `for i = 1:length(n)`
        `F = F + h(n(i));`
    `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is the "novice" for-loop is going to be competitively as fast as any other vectorized solution thanks to improvements in JIT compilation in recent versions of MATLAB.

```
% array of values of n
len = 500;
n = rand(len,1);

% preallocate matrix
X = zeros(len,1001);

% fill rows
for i=1:len
    X(i,:) = h(n(i));    % call function handle
end
out = sum(X,1);
```

The above is as fast as (maybe even faster):

```
XX = cell2mat(arrayfun(h, n, 'UniformOutput',false));
out = sum(XX,1);
```

---

### EDIT:

Here it is computed directly without function handles in a single vectorized call:

```
n = rand(len,1);

t = 0;  % or any other value
out = sum(bsxfun(@times, ...
    sin(bsxfun(@times, n, (0:1e-3:1)*pi)), ...
    cos(n.^2 * t * pi^2/2)), 1);
```

Comment: I agree here regarding JIT.  +1

Comment: If you want, this can be simplified as: `out = sum(sin(bsxfun(@times, n(:), (0:1e-3:1)*pi)))` (note that `t` is always zero, so `g(n,t)` reduces to a vector of ones, which leaves us with `h(n)=f(n)`)

Comment: Thank you very much. As far as t being 0, it won't always be 0, I am doing a time evolution. I just had it there as a placeholder.

Comment: @Sifodeas: I figured as much :) See my edit for a possible one-liner